# how is the formula of Xss in the numerical method for MATLAB derived?

Tags: matlab, discretization

On **pages 193 and 194** of the book 'Control of Power Electronic Converters with Microgrid Applications' by Arindam Ghosh and Firuz Zare (the section can be viewed [**here**](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=bRaIEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA194&lpg=PA194&dq=%22c2d(A1,%20B1,%20D*T)%22&source=bl&ots=EgahMoE-gt&sig=ACfU3U2Mri2uBQQwF3emBDwHSqSnfPJNwg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjXjvzcpu2BAxWAdfUHHeDSBagQ6AF6BAgKEAM#v=onepage&q=%22c2d(A1%2C%20B1%2C%20D*T)%22&f=false)), the author derived the steady-state value **Xss** for the boost converter in equation **(5.91)** and subsequently introduced a numerical method for obtaining the steady-state equation using **'c2d'** in MATLAB.

So, my question is, why does the formula of Xss in the numerical method for MATLAB represent the initial value at the begining of a cycle in steady state? How to derive that formula?

[image]

**Whole derivation:**

I'll provide the entire derivation here, based on what is available from Google Books.

[image]
[image]
[image]